# objective pronoun in front of V-ing from an SAT perspective

Tags: gerunds, present-participles, possessive-pronouns, possessive-vs-oblique

Barron's Grammar Workbook (which claims to be written for those wishing to take "the SAT, ACT, and more") says to use a possessive pronoun before a gerund, and gives the following example:

**Her** asking the question shows that she is alert.

Then it goes on to give two more examples, the second of which is said to contain not a gerund but a participle:

I hope you don't mind **my** intruding on your conversation.

I hope you don't mind **me** intruding on your conversation.

The first version conforms to the rule, and I bet the 2nd is fine in speech. But from a pedantic perspective (which the SAT and the GMAT presumably adhere to), is the second version correct? The present participle following a noun (phrase) functions like a relative clause, so what is grammatically being minded in the second version is not the action of intrusion, but the individual referred to by the pronoun "me."

Comment: Excellent summation. The phrase beginning with **my** refers to the **act** in question, whereas the phrase beginning with **me** refers to the **person** in question. Do you mind my **intruding**? Or, do you mind **me** intruding? It's a subtle difference, and worth noting. The *object* in the first example is the **act** of intruding. In the second one, the *object* is the **person** acting. How you phrase it depends on what you wish to focus on as the object of the sentence.

Comment: The *choice* of pronoun is what creates (or designates) one phrase a gerund and the other not a gerund. The choice of pronoun therefore subtly changes the meaning of the sentence. So it can be argued that a phrase is not a gerund without the possessive pronoun. From your description, it appears the standard tests take that point into consideration, and I would expect it shouldn't be a problem for anyone taking the tests, as long as they fully understand the difference in phrasing and the intended usage for each.